# How to validate format of an Avro schema file to see if it conforms to Apache Avro specification

Tags: avro, jsonschema

Our system must process Avro schemas. Before sending Avro schema file to the server, I want to validate the format of the submitted schema file, to see if it conforms to the Apache Avro specification.

The Avro schema is a Json file, so to do basic validation against the Avro specification, I need a Json schema for the Avro schema file (I know that sounds confusing). Unfortunately, the Apache Avro specification does not provide any definition file for the Avro schema which I could run through a validator.

Does anybody know where I can find a Json Schema defining the structure of the Avro schema file according to the Apache Avro specification?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Avro file, that file contains the schema itself, and therefore would already be "valid". If the file cannot be created with the schema you've given, then you should get an exception (or, at least, any invalid property would be ignored)

You can get that schema via

```
java -jar avro-tools.jar getschema file.avro
```

I'm not aware of a way to use a different schema to get a file without going through the Avro client library reader methods

Comment: Outside of that, more targeted questions should go to the mailing list - https://avro.apache.org/mailing_lists.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
void testSchema() throws IOException {
  Schema classSchema = FooEvent.getClassSchema();
  Schema sourceSchema = new Schema.Parser()
    .parse(getClass()
    .getResourceAsStream("/path/to/FooEvent.avsc"));
  assertThat(classSchema).isEqualTo(sourceSchema);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).